# VBA Append comma to end of integer, don't automatically change format

Tags: excel, vba

My current project is to rewrite a program that was written in 98. Their solution then was to do some in Excel, do this next part in Word, and then back to Excel in the 3rd step. The program syncs 2 files, and their solution is just dandy for 20 files that need to sync - however, now there are around 1,000 files to sync - so I'm working on streamlining the process. The output from the files ranges between X.X and X.XXXXX - I formatted them with

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00000"
```

To make the file easier to read. But the 2nd part is to append a comma, and then a letter regarding the numbers relation: not necessary for the question at hand. When I try to append a comma, Excel attempts to "fix" it and outputs it incorrectly. For example:

> 0.42400
>
> 0.87200
>
> 1.31600
>
> 1.75200

Becomes:

> .424,
>
> .872,
>
> 1.316,
>
> 1.752,

When it should stay at X.XXXXX. Here is what I have tried:

- Changing Excel's options so that decimal identifier is '.' and thousands is ':'.
- `Range("A" & ictr) = Format(Range("A" & ictr) & ",")
- Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00000,"
- Other forums/Google/Bing

I'm really assuming this can be done in Excel, I just cannot find a solution other than re-opening Word, and then back to Excel

Any ideas?

Comment: A non-VBA solution would be to use the formula `=A1&REPT("0",5-LEN(A1))&",")` in a separate column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you state that the

> 2nd part is to append a comma, and then a letter regarding the numbers
>   relation

you're going to need a formula, not just a formatting option.  In your VBA code, select the cells next to the original values, and add this line of code:

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-1],""#0.00000"") & "","""
```

This gets you the formatting and the comma (regardless of the length of the number to the left of the decimal point) -- but to add that last letter, you'll obviously have to modify the formula to meet your specific needs.

Comment: Can you explain what RC[-1] does? I'm not using R1C1 referencing, I'm assuming I can just do `Selection.Formula`, correct?

Comment: Also, is there any way to stop it at just the last row? It gave me 100k+ rows.. :/

Comment: RC[-1] just points the formula to use the cell on the left.  In other words, if you're in cell D3, RC[-1] refers to cell C3.  It isn't used in Excel's grid, however, when you are programming in VBA, most of the time you'll want to use relative references like this one.

Comment: "Stopping it" is 100% dependent on your code, and what the range you've selected is.  It is totally unrelated to formatting the number, which is the original question.  If you need help sizing that, ask a new question.

Comment: Yeah, right after I posted that I saw what it was doing. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert a column and use a formula. Something like this should work

```
Dim TotalRows As Long
TotalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Columns("B:B").Insert

With Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(TotalRows, 2))
    .Formula = "=LEFT(""'""&A1&REPT(""0"",5),7)"
    .Value = .Value
End With

Columns("A:A").Delete
```

Comment: This solution worked, thank you. However, I'm not sure what the '.Formula' is doing, so I will have to look into that. Thank you.

Comment: It is adding the formula =LEFT("'"&A1&REPT("0",5),7). Left will trim the string to 7 characters, A1 gets the text from cell A1, Rept repeats the character "0" 5 times. The reason for prefixing the numbers with ' is so that the contents is treated as a string.

Comment: Actually, after looking further down the files, it appears that there are tens and hundreds. So it could be X.XXXXX to XXXX.XXXXX - the .XXXXX must remain :/